# Fit Gaussian function to black pixels in a checkerboard pattern

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following problem.

**Introduction**

I want to do laser-beam profiling using a Raspberry Pi camera. The camera possesses a color filter array, which means that there is a red, green, or blue transmission filter above each pixel. It looks like this.

[image: Bayer pattern.]

For the wavelength that I am using, the blue and red filters attenuate the beam strongly, which means I end up with the pattern below.

[image]

It looks like a checkerboard pattern.The bright pixels are the ones beneath the green filters.

To fit a Gaussian (or process the image otherwise), I could extract the green pixels, but that would lead to spatial distortion. To fix that, I could use 1 pixel per block of 4, but this is not desirable as I lose resolution. Below are the images when extract the blue, red, and green (red row) and green (blue row) channels.

[image]

**The more general question is**

If I have a checkerboard pattern, how can I use data from the black (or white) pixels without losing information about their spatial location?

Let's say I have an array `data`, and `data[1::2, 1::2]` would give me e.g. the red channel.

My goal (maybe there is an alternative) would be to get a new array `green_information` that contains information from both green channels.
The green channels are `green_red_row = data[::2, 1::2]`
and `green_blue_row = data[1::2, ::2]`.

**Outside of a physics context**:

If I have a checkerboard pattern, how can a fit a Gaussian to the values of the black pixels while keeping in mind that every second pixel is white? It is clear how to fit a standard 2D Gaussian.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you might find [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demosaicing) interesting.
Demosaicing is the general algorithm you probably want in this case. An approach is covered in [this document](https://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/%7Eajitvr/CS663_Fall2016/demosaicing.pdf) which factors in the brightness of a non-green pixel when filling in the green value of the non-green pixel to obtain a complete RGB image. For a red-filtered pixel, the algorithm high-passes the current (red) pixel and neighboring red pixels, and adds the resulting difference to the interpolated green value. This way, some per-pixel local texture information is still available after demosaicing.